# How do I call another class from main class in android studio?

Tags: android

MainActivity.java does not extend fragment. I created MainActivityFragment class which extends fragment. Now how do I call it from the MainActivity class?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? and provide the code that you have made so far.

Comment: @Amisha - Be so kind and provide what you have tried so far. At least you are expected to show the java files you created and a simple explanation of what you intend to do.

Comment: https://github.com/Amisha95/PopularMovies1

Answer (score 1):

You obviously do not know what Activity and Fragment are and how you should use it because your question doesn't make sense.

I recommend to start from reading about [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), [Activities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and then try to approach your problem again.

Comment: What I exactly wanted to do was make a button in MainActivity, clicking on which I want to display some images in my app. Yes, I'm very new to android development. MainActivity.java does not extend Fragment class. That is why I made a class MainActivityFragment.java that extends a fragment class.

Comment: Now the problem is that I'm getting an error in::::  View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false); I'm unable to figure out what the problem is. And this is why my app is crashing.

Comment: Try it without the container:     View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.poster_layout, null, false); because it's inflate the view inside this container, but - you are also adding the view to the fragment. If it doesn't solve the bug so please share with us the exception

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like

```
      MainActivityFragment maf = new MainActivityFragment();
      af.setArguments(extras);
      getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                .add(R.id.container, maf)
                                 .commit();
```

For more information see the documentation for regarding Android Fragments here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html